# React Admin / building Data Provider via 'ra-data-graphql' library - auto-injected `raFetchType` param is undefined

Tags: graphql, react-admin

I'm trying to create a dataProvider via `ra-data-graphql`, as described in the [library's README](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-data-graphql/README.md), and am successfully passing in the introspection response to the `buildQuery` method, but the `raFetchType`  param in my `buildQuery` method is always undefined, and the query mapping that is supposed to happen fails. It appears as though the `raFetchType` should be populated automatically by the library, or maybe I'm (or the documentation) missing something.

Do I need to provide some extra option when injecting `buildCustomQuery` into `buildGraphQLProvider`?

**What you were expecting:**
`raFetchType` is defined (I'm assuming as one of 'GET_LIST', 'GET_ONE', etc.)

**What happened instead:**
the `raFetchType` param in `buildQuery` (called `aorFetchType` in the library's source code) is always undefined

**Related code:**

```js
// App.tsx

const [dataProvider, setDataProvider] = useState<DataProvider>();
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: // my graphql API URL
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: cache,
  link: link,
});

useEffect(() => {
  buildGraphQLProvider({
    client: { client },
    buildQuery: buildCustomQuery,
    introspection: {
      schema, // JSON previously fetched from my GraphQL API
      operationNames: introspectionOperationNames, // function that maps the 'Country' resource to the correct query name for 'GET_LIST'
      include: ['Country'], // just trying it out with a single Resource first
    },
  }).then((dataProvider: any) => {
    setDataProvider(dataProvider);
  })
}, []);
```

```js
// this is called via `buildGraphQLProvider` on init
export const buildCustomQuery = (introspectionResults: any) => (raFetchType: any, resourceName: any, params: any) => {
   // the introspectionResults contain the 4 properties listed here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-graphql#specify-your-queries-and-mutations
   // including the 'Country' resource with the mapped query name
   // however, `raFetchType` is undefined, and so no query can ever be returned. 
   // I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseResponse' of undefined' on ra-data-graphql/esm/index.js:113
    const resource = introspectionResults.resources.find((r: IntrospectionResource) => r.type.name === resourceName);
    switch (raFetchType) {
        case 'GET_LIST':
            return {
                query: gql`query ${resource[raFetchType].name}($id: ID) {
                    data: ${resource[raFetchType].name}(id: $id) {
                           ...
                        }
                    }
                }`,
                variables: params, // params = { id: ... }
                parseResponse: (response: any) => response.data,
            }
            break;
        // ... other types handled here
        default:
            return undefined;
    }
}
```

**Environment**

- React-admin version: 3.11.0
- React version: 17.0.1
- Browser: Chrome
- Stack trace: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseResponse' of undefined at raDataProvider (index.js:113)`